# No se genera la carpeta dist al construir el programa

Tags: java, netbeans

Tengo un problema, no sé si lo esté haciendo bien, tengo un programa de Java que lo he terminado y funciona sin problemas, al hacer clean and build en NetBeans 12.4 no me genera la carpeta dist, sin embargo me crea una llamada Target, quiero crear un ejecutable de mi programa, pero el ejecutable que se crea no hace nada.

Comment: ¿Maven, Gradle o Ant?

Comment: no conozco lo que es maven, pero veo que una de las carpetas dentro de Target se llama maven-archiver